# Can't access to correct chrome profile with selenium and that make the new one under the same directory

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Updated(21Apr2021)
I found the problem. Thank to @simpleApp to point out the problem. I didn't notice the space character could make a problem.Now it's working well

```
option.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\yen.ld\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\") 
option.add_argument("--profile-directory=Profile 1")  #no space
```

Hello i'm using the newest selenium and python and chrome driver . And i'm facing an issue that. Even though i input correct directory but after run the code then it make other profile name under the same directory. Basically these 2 profiles will co-exist

This is my code and i tried some option but no solution till now..Is there any solution about it? Thank you guys so much

```
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\NEO\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\")
option.add_argument("--profile-directory= Profile 6")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe', options=option)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: there is extra space in chromedriver profiles, pls check -->  Data\Profile vs Data\ Profile.

Comment: Yes you're right but the problem is still there. The root cause from my code?

Comment: would you mind sharing what is the issue here? is chrome driver not loading your profile? and how you found that chrome driver is not fired as the way you want.

Comment: @simpleApp No you are correct. i miss understood it. btw if i have a css_selector as below then how can i input a random number in it properly  Click_link  = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.ml-4:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(1) > h3:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1)').click()  #nth-child(5) link number ( and i want to generate a random and put it on this command) Thank you so much

Comment: you may have to look for another method to identify this selector, when you say random, you mean predetermined I think. try this but pls note I have not tested this on driver. `one='1'
four='4'
five='5'
var_place_holder=f'div.ml-{four}:nth-child({five}) > div:nth-child({one}) > h3:nth-child({one}) > a:nth-child({one})'
print(var_place_holder)`